# Converting Combinatorica graph to standard graph type

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorica, igraphm

I'm trying to count triangles in random d-regular graphs. Combinatorica has a function `RegularGraph`, which gives me the random graph and IGraphM has a function `IGCliqueSizeCounts` that'll count k-cliques in a graph.

So in theory, `Needs["Combinatorica"]; Needs["IGraphM"]; IGCliqueSizeCounts[RegularGraph[d, n]][[3]]` should be what I need. The only issue is that it seems as though `RegularGraph` is giving a graph type that `IGCliqueSizeCounts` doesn't recognize. Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Which Mathematica version are you using? You can use `$Version` command to find out.

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of triangles in a WL Graph, you can use

```
TriangleCount[g_Graph] := Tr[MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 3]]/6
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that Combinatorica's `RegularGraph` does not sample regular graphs uniformly. This is stated in [the Combinatorica Book](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Eskiena/combinatorica/) which you *should* get if you use Combinatorica. The statistics of triangle counts you get this way will not be representative of the triangle counts of all $k$-regular graphs. To better understand why this sampling is not uniform, first see how it works (Combinatorica Book), then check the gentle introduction to this topic [in this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/2632-072X/abced5).

IGraph/M has functions which can be used for uniform sampling. Note that `IGKRegularGame` will again *not* sample uniformly. `IGDegreeSequenceGame` has one method that samples uniformly, namely `"ConfigurationModelSimple"`. This is fast for small degrees (e.g. 3-regular), but quickly becomes unusably slow for larger ones.

Yet another way is to first generate one graph with the given degrees using `IGRealizeDegreeSequence` then reshuffle it using `IGRewire`. In the limit of an infinite number of reshuffling steps, this method samples uniformly. In practice, maybe 10 or more times the number of edges will be a good guideline for how many reshuffling steps to make. This method works reasonable fast for larger degrees as well.